Python setup.py query
I am not able to understand where I made the mistake while working with setup.py file.
Code of setup.py file
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='banking',
    version='2.0',
    packages=['com', 'com.home', 'com.home.fd', 'com.home.loan', 'com.home.savings'],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='Palan Mondal',[enter image description here][1]
    author_email='',
    description='This is for testing purpose'
)

enter image description here
PS C:\Users\palan> cd C:\Users\palan\PycharmProjects\Banking
PS C:\Users\palan\PycharmProjects\Banking> pip install .
Processing c:\users\palan\pycharmprojects\banking
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: banking
  Building wheel for banking (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for banking: filename=banking-2.0-py3-none-any.whl size=2432 sha256=33a8f1faba754311cf658baa1e31b8da2c5225be5417b0f85ea5112750de3665
  Stored in directory: C:\Users\palan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ephem-wheel-cache-q29k5ryt\wheels\ab\ff\0c\76332b8efa62e291752fb443ca3338e62883e1f06f9d1caa26
Successfully built banking
Installing collected packages: banking
Successfully installed banking-2.0

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 24.1.2 -> 24.3.1
[notice] To update, run: C:\Users\palan\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
PS C:\Users\palan\PycharmProjects\Banking> pip show banking
Name: banking
Version: 2.0
Summary: This is for testing purpose
Home-page:
Author: Palan Mondal
Author-email:
License:
Location: C:\Users\palan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
PS C:\Users\palan\PycharmProjects\Banking> python
Python 3.11.9 (tags/v3.11.9:de54cf5, Apr  2 2024, 10:12:12) [MSC v.1938 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import banking
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'banking'
>>> import pymysql
>>>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The python packaging system has two separate concepts that can both be refered to as a "package". To disambiguate them they are called "distribution package" and "import package". Distribution packages are the names by which pip and pypi refer to packages. An import package is the modules that are made available to import in python.
It is a good idea to make sure these match, but that is not always the case. In your instance, you have created a distribution package called banking and import packages starting with com.home.
You can see which import packages a distribution package may have installed by running: pip show -f <distribution-package>. For example:
pip show -f pip

gives:
Name: pip
...
Files:
  ...
  pip/__init__.py
  pip/__main__.py
  pip/__pip-runner__.py
  ...

For more details on distribution packages vs import packages see:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/distribution-package-vs-import-package/

I have run the query you mentioned but no file showing under the distribution packages PS C:\Users\palan> pip show -f banking
Name: banking
Version: 2.0
Summary: This is for testing purpose
Home-page:
Author: Palan Mondal
Author-email:
License:
Location: C:\Users\palan\PycharmProjects\Banking
Editable project location: C:\Users\palan\PycharmProjects\Banking
Requires:
Required-by:
Files:
Cannot locate RECORD or installed-files.txt

Sounds like your wheel didn't build and/or install correctly. There are multiple bits of evidence that you have tried to build this package in different ways. You should start again and create a dedicated virtual environment to install your package into. Once your  venv is activated, you should install the required packages to develop a package (setuptools and wheel). Then create the wheel (python setup.py bdist_wheel). Then inspect the wheel using a zip program to check it has the required files. And finally install (pip install dist/banking-2.0-py3-none-any.whl).
